# finding apache modules

Tags: apache-2.2, opensuse

I need to find mod_suexec and mod_rewrite for OpenSUSE 11 x64, as neither module came with my install. I've had most modules I need be included in Apache installs in the past so I'm not too familiar with where I go to find these.

I've tried zypper which wasn't too much help, and looked for existing .so's and even just the source code (which would probably take me a lot more work to get working).

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both mod_rewrite and mod_suexec are [included in the `apache2` package](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/11.3/x86_64/apache2-2.2.15-3.7.x86_64.html). If they are missing then you'll need to reinstall that package.